# Struggling with post multipart/form-data including file and attributes

Tags: python-3.x, https, python-requests

I'm using Requests for a program that interfaces with a server that has a well documented API, except for file upload which uses multipart/form-data including file and attributes. Every other request using JSON and that has not been an issue.

The docs say that the header must contain `content-type:multipart/form-data` but I have realized that requests does that automatically. It then lists a number of text attributes in the form of `author.fullName: Heidi Walker` and then a file attribute in the form of `content: [physical file]`

I have a working example in Postman but I can't get it to work with Requests. This is the code I have:

```
header = {
    'session_id':sID,
}

# These are the required text attributes from the API docs + the actual file
fileInfo = { 
     'author.fullName' : 'Fred',
     'category.guid' : 'xxx',
     'description' : 'Data Sheet',
     'format' : 'PDF',
     'private' : 'false',
     'storageMethodName' : 'FILE',
     'title ' : 'Test Datasheet',
     'content': open(path, 'rb')
}     

resp = requests.post(url + '/files', headers = header, files = fileInfo)
```

I keep getting back 400 errors from the server.

Also, is their any way to see the formatted body of the request? So I can check that the boundary tags have been added correctly and compare to what Postman created?

I have been struggling with this for way to long so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I was able to enable logging with the logging module as outlined on this page: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/

Inspecting the body of the request I see:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author.fullName"; filename="author.fullName"\r\n\r\nFred\r\n
```

What I would like to see (working postman example) is:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"author.fullName\"\r\n\r\nFred\r\n
```

It seems that `filename="author.fullName"` is being inserted on every line.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working, here is the code if anyone else is struggling with this.

```
multi = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'author.fullName' : 'Automatic Upload',
            'category.guid' : 'XXX',
            'description' : 'Data Sheet',
            'edition' : '01',
            'format' : 'PDF',
            'private' : 'false',
            'storageMethodName' : 'FILE',
            'title ' : title,
            'content': (fileName, open(path, 'rb'), 'application/pdf')}
)

mpHeader = {
    'Content-Type': multi.content_type,
    'session_id':sID,
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}

resp = requests.post(url + '/files', headers = mpHeader, data = multi)
```